# Is this a valid sum formula for rational functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-writing

Consider:

$$\frac{a(x)}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}}$$

Is the expressions above equivalent to:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(x)}{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}}$$ ??

Comment: @Nilan, how so? The claim seems to be a reincarnation of $\frac1{a+b}=\frac1a+\frac1b$ (which, of course, is wrong).

Comment: I delete that Comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{a(x)}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}} = \dfrac{a(x)}{1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \cdots}.$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a(x)}{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}} = a(x)( 1 - \dfrac{1}{x^2} + \dfrac{1}{x^4} - \dfrac{1}{x^6} + \cdots ).$

Assuming everything makes sense, these two are not same in general.

Answer (score 0):

Take ${a(x)}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}}$

Answer (score 0):

If you try $a(x) = 1$, then the first expression converges for $|x| < 1$ and diverges for $|x| > 1$, while the second expression converges for $|x| > 1$ and diverges for $|x| < 1$.